# boost asio for windows

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I apologize, but this question sounds silly to even to me, but maybe it will help someone else also, so I am asking it:

I downloaded & installed the Windows Pre-Built libraries for Booste 1.67 (MSVC 14.1 x64). https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/binaries/

But when I look in the folder for ./lib-msvc-14.1/ I do not see a DLL or .lib for ASIO.

Is it included in a different .dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Boost.Asio is a [header-only library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html):

> By default, Boost.Asio is a header-only library.

(But parts of Boost.Asio depend on other Boost libraries that must be compiled)

Comment: So since there are 160 pre-built library DLL's, I am assuming that ASIO is using one or more of them. Which one's should I include?

Comment: If you use CMake, you should not need to specify them explicitly. If you don't, just look for missing symbols and add the corresponding libraries.

Comment: I probably need newbie help for vs2017. I have done tons in c#, which makes it easy- just add reference. I will do some homework and figure out how to do this for c++, which seems quite different.

Comment: I've always built my own libs. It should be as simple as, from a command prompt in the boost root: `bootstrap.bat` then `./b2`. If you have more than one flavor of VS like 2015 you would do `,/b2 toolset=msvc-14` your libs should land in `$(BOOST_ROOT)/stage/lib` See [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) and [this](https://codeyarns.com/2014/06/06/how-to-build-boost-using-visual-studio/)

Comment: Since I was able to get the correct version boost for VS2017 (C++ std libs). I don't even need: https://codeyarns.com/2014/06/06/how-to-build-boost-using-visual-studio/ All I had to do is add the headers and the libs in the build settings.